# AppEngine get/post on webapp2.RequestHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was receiving `405 method not supported` errors on `get` requests to my save controller, so I created a `get` method which just calls the existing `post` one as follows:

```
class Save(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.post()

    def post(self):
        #...
```

This seems to be working, but is there a more Pythonic way to define both request handlers at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily alias one method to another:

```
class Save(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        #...

    get = post
```

**But** although I don't know anything about your application, you shouldn't alias GET to POST like this: the two methods have different semantics. GET is a *safe method* — it must only retrieve data and *not* update or store it — while POST is an *unsafe method* — it requests the server to store or update the data in the request. See "[Safe methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods)" in Wikipedia.